# FragmentPageAdapter not working properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I am using FragmentPagerAdapter to navigate between 4 Fragments in my app. But I am facing a strange problem. When I debugged my App I found that the Index value in the getItem loads to 0 when MainActivity is started and so the Fargment at 0th index is loaded and thereafter the index changes to 1 and the fragment at 1st index is loaded and because of this the sequence of getting the fragment is a little bit disturbed. I dont know if I am missing out at something. But I really cant figure out the problem. Here is my FragmentPagerAdapter Class:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    Context context;

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new FragmentA();
        case 1:
            return new FragmentB();
        case 2:
            return new FragmentC();
        case 3:
            return new FragmentD();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 4;
    }

}
```

This class is not behaving the way i Want it to work. The UI gets loaded according to the way I want. I mean , Suppose if i click on the Tab of FragmentB(), The index would be generated of the next Fragment i.e. FragmentC() but on my device, I will see the FragmentB() I know I am unable to explain the issue properly but still i would be grateful if anyone can help but please dont downvote. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: the problem is at the beginning? I didn't clearly understand the problem to be honest.

Comment: post your code on `onTabSelected`

Comment: @Override
 public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
  
  viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

 }

Comment: Not sure I have completely understood but ```FragmentStatePagerAdapter``` load fragments around (forward and backward from...) the starting position. This behaviour is  controlled by the adapter ```setOffscreenPageLimit(int number)```. The Javadoc states that the default offset is 1, meaning that when clicking "Frag B" following debug activity will note "Frag C" loading...owing to this offset (Frag B was loaded when Frag A/Frag C was loaded).

Comment: @OceanLife this was the reason . Thanks :)

Comment: @Puneetr90, I've added this as an answer so that the next person to come across similar behaviour can clearly see the reason. If you could accept then that would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I have completely understood but `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` load fragments around (forward and backward from...) the starting position. This behaviour is controlled by the adapter `setOffscreenPageLimit(int number)`. The Javadoc states that the default offset is 1, meaning that when clicking "Frag B" following debug activity will note "Frag C" loading...owing to this offset (Frag B was loaded when Frag A/Frag C was loaded).